# How to get 1 record on the basis of two column values in a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

The query is

```
select distinct b.UserID , cast(b.entrytime as date) ,count(*) as UserCount
from [dbo].[person] as a
join [dbo].[personcookie] as b
on a.UserID = b.UserID
where cast (b.entrytime as date) >= '08/21/2020'
and cast (b.leavetime as date) <= '08/27/2020' and a.distinction = 99
group by cast(b.entrytime as date), b.UserID
```

If same UserID has count more than 1 for same date, It should consider as 1. Now as it is shown in the image that `USERID` **10** has count 1 for 2020-08-26 and `USERID` **10** has count 2 for '2020-08-27'. It should show that `user ID` **10** has total count 2 for `2020-08-26 and 2020-08-27' (because for 2020-08-27 the count should be 1) as per the requirement.
I have added the image of tables and what output i want
[image]

Comment: Why do you want the count at all if it is always 1?

Comment: Why use a `DISTINCT` and a `GROUP BY`? If your `GROUP BY` isn't returnomg distinct row sets already then the problem is your `GROUP BY`. `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` should normally never be in the same query, as it almost always points to one being redundent (the `DISTINCT`) or a flawed `GROUP BY` clause. Also, `person` starts with a `p`, not an `a` (it doesn't even have an `a` in it). [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Because there is multiple day data and for single day if same user is signing in multiple times it should be considered as 1. But if same user is signing in each day the count will increase.

Comment: write your output in an excel and please update in the question. In the current required  output what should be the value in second column

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty explained image is attached. please see

Comment: On a side note: Be careful with your dates. `'08/21/2020'` is a string that the DBMS may or may not be able to convert into a date. This depends on session settings. Use the unambiguous standard format `'2020-08-21'` instead. (In standard SQL that literal would be preceded with the keyword `DATE` (i.e. `DATE '2020-08-21'`, but I don't know whether SQL Server finally supports this syntax.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want one result row per user, so group by user, not by user and date. You want to count dates per user, but each day only once. This is a distinct count.

```
select 
  p.userid,
  count(distinct cast(pc.entrytime as date)) as date_count
from dbo.person as p
join dbo.personcookie as pc on pc.userid = p.userid
where p.distinction = 99
  and pc.entrytime >= '2020-08-08'
  and pc.leavetime < '2020-08-28'
group by p.userid
order by p.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `dense_rank()`:

```
select p.UserID, cast(pc.entrytime as date), 
       dense_rank() over (partition by p.userID order by min(pc.entrytime)) as usercount
from [dbo].[person] p join
     [dbo].[personcookie] pc
     on pc.UserID = p.UserID
where cast(pc.entrytime as date) >= '2020-08-21' and
      cast(pc.leavetime as date) <= '2020-08-27'
group by cast(pc.entrytime as date), p.UserID;
```

Notes:

- The only "real" change is using `dense_rank()`, which enumerates the days for a given user.
- Use meaningful table aliases, rather than arbitrary letters.
- Use standard date/time constants.  In SQL Server, that is either YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: The result is same as i shown in the attached image. If there is multiple day data and for single day if same user is signing in multiple times it should be considered as 1. But if same user is signing in each day the count will increase like if USERID 10 is signing in for today and yesterday the count for UserID 10 should be 2.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you please give the sample data and expected results?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty . . . It took me a bit of time, but the OP basically wants to enumerate the days someone has entered, not count the numbers on a given day.